# How to count odd numbers in a row of numbers in perl?

Tags: regex, perl, numbers, int

I have numbers like these:

```
15-84-315-164 
11-76-132-310
44-20-958-2732
```

And I need to know how many odd numbers are in a row.

For example in *15-84-315-164* there are *6* odd numbers.

I want to use perl and maybe regex for the solution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @data = <DATA>;
chomp @data;

process_line($_) for @data;

sub process_line {
    my $data = shift;

    my $count;
    my @digits = $data =~ /(\d)/g;

    for my $digit (@digits) {
        $digit%2 ? $count->{odd}++ : $count->{even}++;
    }

    say ' Odd: ' . $count->{odd} . ' Even: ' . $count->{even} . ' Line: ' . $data;
}


__DATA__
15-84-315-164 
11-76-132-310
44-20-958-2732
```

Output

```
 Odd: 6 Even: 4 Line: 15-84-315-164
 Odd: 7 Even: 3 Line: 11-76-132-310
 Odd: 4 Even: 7 Line: 44-20-958-2732
```

Comment: so what's wrong with the code you provided? If it works, what's your question? If it doesn't, please provide the expected and the actual behavior and explain how you tried to debug and how that failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $string = "15-84-315-164";
my ($number) = scalar( @{[ $string=~/(1|3|5|7|9)/gi ]} );
print $number
```

Below is the regex.

```
(1|3|5|7|9)
```

What this basically does is finds if odd number is present.

Once we have the regex, we then just count the number of times the regex appeared by using scalar.

Comment: Faster and simpler : `my $num_odd_digits = $string =~ tr/13579//;`